# how create a sleep mode for servers

Tags: sleep, jelastic, sleep-mode

for my jelastic servers as i dont use much would like to put them in something similar to sleep, that they are only activated in http request
i saw for trial accounts sleeps something, but would like to know if there would be a way to do it with a normal account.
For instance i had the idea of making a script to turn them off at night, but i dont know how to wake up.
any ideas are welcom
https://ops-docs.jelastic.com/jca-sleep-results

https://ops-docs.jelastic.com/jca-sleep-results

Answer (score 0):

There is a start stop scheduler in the marketplace within the Jelastic dashboard. Check "Env Start/Stop Scheduler" in Marketplace > Add-Ons.

If you're interested in the code, or can't find that add-on at your Jelastic provider, you can find it at https://github.com/jelastic-jps/start-stop-scheduler

Note that this is not quite the same as sleep (it will not wake up automatically when there's a http request) - it will be completely offline during the hours that you specify.